# Add Answer to peerJS script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, peerjs

I'm not good in english but i try explain my problem.
I'm using PeerJS to make call audio between to users.
And I use this example: http://cdn.peerjs.com/demo/videochat and it's work.
But I want add answer or not answer to user in this script. How I can do it?
This is my script:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>PeerJS - Video chat example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.confirm.js"></script>

  <script src="./peer.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    // Compatibility shim
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    // PeerJS object
    var peer = new Peer({ key: 'lwjd5qra8257b9', debug: 3});

    peer.on('open', function(){
      $('#my-id').text(peer.id);
    });

    // Receiving a call
    peer.on('call', function(call){
      // Answer the call automatically (instead of prompting user) for demo purposes

        //here is Ansswer

      call.answer(window.localStream);
      step3(call);

    });
    peer.on('error', function(err){
      alert(err.message);
      // Return to step 2 if error occurs
      step2();
    });

    // Click handlers setup
    $(function(){
      $('#make-call').click(function(){
        // Initiate a call!
        var call = peer.call($('#callto-id').val(), window.localStream);

        step3(call);
      });

      $('#end-call').click(function(){
        window.existingCall.close();
        step2();
      });

      // Retry if getUserMedia fails
      $('#step1-retry').click(function(){
        $('#step1-error').hide();
        step1();
      });

      // Get things started
      step1();
    });

    function step1 () {
      // Get audio/video stream
      navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false}, function(stream){
        // Set your video displays
        $('#my-video').prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(stream));

        window.localStream = stream;
        step2();
      }, function(){ $('#step1-error').show(); });
    }

    function step2 () {
      $('#step1, #step3').hide();
      $('#step2').show();
    }

    function step3 (call) {
      // Hang up on an existing call if present
      if (window.existingCall) {
        window.existingCall.close();
      }

      // Wait for stream on the call, then set peer video display
      call.on('stream', function(stream){
        $('#their-video').prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(stream));
      });

      // UI stuff
      window.existingCall = call;
      $('#their-id').text(call.peer);
      call.on('close', step2);
      $('#step1, #step2').hide();
      $('#step3').show();
    }

  </script>

    <style>
    .pure-g {
        width: 350px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .pure-u-1-3{
        width: 100%;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="pure-g">
      <!-- Video area -->
      <div class="pure-u-2-3" id="video-container" style='display: none'>
        <video id="their-video" autoplay></video>
      </div>

      <!-- Steps -->
      <div class="pure-u-1-3">
        <h2>SMA Voice Chat</h2>

        <!-- Get local audio/video stream -->
        <div id="step1">
          <p>Please click `allow` on the top of the screen so we can access your webcam and microphone for calls.</p>
          <div id="step1-error">
            <p>Failed to access the webcam and microphone. Make sure to run this demo on an http server and click allow when asked for permission by the browser.</p>
            <a href="#" class="pure-button pure-button-error" id="step1-retry">Try again</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Make calls to others -->
        <div id="step2">
          <p>Your id: <span id="my-id">...</span></p>
          <p>Share this id with others so they can call you.</p>
          <h3>Make a call</h3>
          <div class="pure-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Call user id..." id="callto-id">
            <a href="#" class="pure-button pure-button-success" id="make-call">Call</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Call in progress -->
        <div id="step3">
          <p>Currently in call with <span id="their-id">...</span></p>
          <p><a href="#" class="pure-button pure-button-error" id="end-call">End call</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Did the answer below worked for u without any errors?? because when i tried that it doesn't show any notification for me.

Comment: yes it work with me.

Comment: this is my post. it would be so helpful if u can find any errors in my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182914/video-chatting-using-peerjs-shows-errors-always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PeerJS, but I think you may try to rewrite your `peer.on('call',...)` part as follows:

```
peer.on('call', function(call){
  $.confirm({
    text: "Receive a call?",
    confirm: function(button) {
      //user clicked "ok"
      call.answer(window.localStream);
      step3(call); 
    },
    cancel: function(button) {
      //user clicked "cancel"
    }
  });
});
```